# How to scan all web ips

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know how in JS I can go about scanning all the ip's of the internet (not at the same time). In order to then see if Minecraft servers exist on these IPs. (I just don't know how to generate all the ips), is there a definite list of 4.3 billion ips?

Thanks in advance!

So I don't know how to go about it

Comment: Start from `0.0.0.0` and scan up to `255.255.255.255`?  (Though there are ranges you can omit.  But that probably won't be your rate determining step here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid solution is just to scan all ip`s

```
const main = async () => {

for (let i1 = 0; i1<=255; i1++) {
for (let i2 = 0; i2<=255; i2++) {
for (let i3 = 0; i3<=255; i3++) {
for (let i4 = 0; i4<=255; i4++) {
  const ip = i1+'.'+i2+'.'+i3+'.'+i4;
  // do something with await
  console.log(ip);
}}}}

}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Gotta upvote the elegant simplicity of it, being exactly what the OP asked for.  Though I wonder if the OP has done the math on how many years this will run...

Comment: 4 * 10^9 operations. Without actions it`s a something like 15-20 seconds
With actions it may be a few hours

Comment: Depends on the "actions".  If the loop *does nothing* then it'll be over fairly soon.  But the question implies that each action is going to involve a round trip to a server, potentially with a timeout.  How many of those actions per second are reasonably expected?  At 100 network round trips per second, we're looking at over a year.  A reasonable throughput for this functionality (from consumer hardware/connections) is probably closer to 10 per second.  If many of the requests hang, what's the OP's timeout period?  1/10th of a second?  Unlikely.  This is going to take a *long* time.

Comment: Hm.. I think you`re right..